# Codeigniter giving 404 but htaccess correct

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using Codeigniter 3 and have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Allow redirect.phps which are setup 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} register.php
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z]{2})/register.php /redirect.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?register.php /redirect.php/uk [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z]{2})/images/(.*)$ /images/$1/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/([^/]+)/ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|jscript|convert\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have tested this on http://htaccess.mwl.be/ and the format is correct and I'm told:

- The new url is http://my.local/redirect.php/uk
- The tests are stopped because of the L in your RewriteRule options.

Great. But for some reason I'm getting a Codeigniter 404 page?? Surely Codeigniter should never be even seeing my code? If I put a simple hello+exit in my index.php file I can clearly see Codeigniter is being passed the params so what on earth have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to set the $base_url in your config.php file?

Comment: Yes - its set to something like $config['base_url'] = 'http://my.local/';

Comment: Okay, assuming that your application is in your root directory try changing the .htaccess like this 
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @Ukuser32 what is your site URL?

Comment: It would be my.local - I'm testing it locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `.htaccess` like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Or this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thats great @Niranjan thanks for that. I've tried the second half and replaced my Codeigniter bit but am I not right in thinking that my [L] of my original file should have stopped the Codeigniter rules ever actually matching?? Why did it get to that bit?